# How to replace string with Java

Tags: java, replace

I want to replace the string like ABC.eee -> eee

It means that I want to erase string before dot if string has dot (.), if string doesn't have dot, nothing should happen.

I tried regex compression, split etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of the dot and call `substring` if found.

```java
int idx = str.indexOf('.');
if (idx != -1) str = str.substring(idx + 1);
```

You could also use a regular expression with `String#replaceAll`.

```java
str = str.replaceAll("^[^.]*\\.", "");
```

Comment: That regular expression in the last line could be as simple as `".*\\."`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It depends on what the output should be with multiple dots.

Answer (score 0):

First you can find the index of dot, then you can get substring from the next index below the index of dot until the end of string.

```
String s1 = ".ABCeee";
int index = s1.indexOf('.');
if(index != -1)
    s1 = s1.substring(index + 1, s1.length());
```

Comment: Please use real words, so use "you", not "U".